# How Testcafe handle login errors?

Tags: javascript, authentication, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm testing a website that needs authentication with different users. It's working most of the time but sometimes, login fails and Testcafé doesn't detect it before running into the actual test code. Rather than raising an error into the login method, it fails when finding a DOM element in the test page. So it keeps the wrong login information and other tests with the same user will fail too.

I know the way to detect a login error on my website but I can't say to Testcafé:

"Hey! Something wrong appends when login, don't save login information for this user and try again in next tests"

**EDIT:**
Rather than using hardcoded login information, I use a separate file `logins.ts` with the following structure and I adapt it to add `loggedIn` and `role` fields :

```
adminUserCredentials: { login: 'mylogin', pwd: 'mypass', role: null, loggedIn: false }
```

Then I use it as follow:

```js
function createUserForSpecificEnv(user: User, baseUrl: string): Role {
    if(!user.loggedIn) {
        user.role = Role(baseUrl, async t => {
            await t
                .wait(1000)
                .typeText('#loginInput', user.login)
                .typeText('#passwordInput', user.pwd)
                .click('#Btn')

            if(await Selector('#user-info').visible) {
                user.loggedIn = true
            }
        })
    }
    return user.role
}

const adminUserRole = getRole(adminUserCredentials)

test("test 1", async t => {
    t.useRole(adminUserRole)
}) // The test go on the login page, auth failed (expected) and can't find #user-info (expected)

test("test 2", async t => {
    t.useRole(adminUserRole)
}) // The test doesn't go to the login page and directly says : can't find #user-info
```

But it's still not working... TestCafe tries to log in on the first test and then it directly reuses the same login information.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you :-)

**EDIT 2**
I clarify the fact that I use variable to store the role (see comments)

Answer (score 3):

If login fail is expected I'd suggest not using [`Role`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/role/constructor.html) for this particular test. You can extract an authentication logiс into a separate function and use it in this test directly and in the `Role` constructor:

```
const logIn = async t => {
    //login steps
};

user.role = Role(baseUrl, logIn);

test("test 1", async t => {
    await logIn(t);    
}); // The test go on the login page, auth failed (expected) and can't find #user-info (expected)

test("test 2", async t => {
    t.useRole(adminUserRole)
});
```

Comment: I finally move to something likes your example even if I lose some minutes during tests run.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can check some Selector on the last step of Role initialization to make sure that you are correctly logged in. If you are not, you need to recreate your role for further usage in the next tests. Please see the following code, which demonstrates my idea:

```
import { Role, Selector } from 'testcafe';

let role     = null;
let loggedIn = false;

function getRole() {
    if (!loggedIn) {
        role = new Role('http://example.com', async t => {
            console.log('role initialize');

            // await t.typeText('#login', 'login');
            // await t.typeText('#password', 'password');
            // await t.click('#signin');

            // NOTE: ensure that we are actually logged in
            if(await Selector('#user_profile').exists)
                loggedIn = true;
        });
    }

    return role;
}

fixture `fixture`
    .page `../pages/index.html`;

test(`test1`, async t => {
    await t.useRole(getRole());
});

test(`test2`, async t => {
    await t.useRole(getRole());
});

test(`test3`, async t => {
    await t.useRole(getRole());
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Your code is working but when I try to adapt it to my project it's not working anymore. Please see my post edit.

Comment: I did not find any problems in your edited sample. It looks just like my example. Probably the issue lies somewhere else. Please provide a working example demonstrating it.

Comment: I think I find the difference between my case and your example. You directly call `getRole()` in your test. On the other hand, I defined variables like that: `const adminUser = getRole()`. I edit the question.

Comment: Please note that when you try to switch to a previously used role within the same session, this role will not be executed again. It is the most valuable benefit of using roles because it allows to significantly reduce testing time (learn about other benefits in [this topic](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html#why-use-roles)). That's why you need to create a new Role (see the example above) each time you try to switch to it.

Comment: Yes, I already see this page and I understand the great benefits of reusing same roles. I want to keep this feature because we have more than 100 tests that currently takes 15 minutes to run. I can't imagine the time that it will take if the authentification should run again. So, recreate a new role is for me a workaround but not a viable solution in my case.